# Any advantage to using @2x or @3x images in UIImage if the image is being scaled down?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, core-graphics

Let's say I have a UIImage with a native size of 300x300pixels, and the image will be scaled down to various sizes, down to say 100x100. In this scenario, is there any advantage to generating @2x and @3x versions? The @3x would be the 300x300 pixel version.

In other words, will the OS make use of the extra pixels on 3x screens if handed a 300x300 pixel image and scaling it down to 1/3 size? I'm trying to determine if generating the smaller images is a waste of space in this scenario.

Comment: normal (no suffix), `@2x` suffix, `@3x` suffix are used in different resolution of iOS devices. You must generate all three versions in order to have best display results (non-blurry) for all iOS devices.

Comment: You can also use vector images which comes in iOS 7 and getting popular with more device resolution for this you don't have to make (@2x or @3x) Only one image is used for all resolutions

Comment: Try this XCode plugin.  https://github.com/rickytan/RTImageAssets

Comment: No there isn't any advantage and also its not a good practice to use images bigger than necessary as it eventually increases your build size.